# SSH permission error

Tags: linux, ssh

I have seen many posts related to ssh permission denies but still mine is clueless.

```
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/siddharthan/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/siddharthan/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/siddharthan/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/siddharthan/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/siddharthan/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/siddharthan/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

From the above I can say it is searching for the private key in the `.ssh` folder. But in the following snippet, it is clear that the respective files are in the `.ssh` folder.

```
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 siddharthan siddharthan 751 Apr 27 17:40 keyforHpc
-rw-r--r-- 1 siddharthan siddharthan 606 Apr 27 17:40 keyforHpc.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 siddharthan siddharthan 222 Apr 27 19:29 known_hosts
```

I have been using this for about a month and I just started getting this problem today. Can anyone please provide some suggestions?

Comment: Even though pvt key is present in folder you have to verify the public key in other end. Missing either one may cause issue.

Comment: The timestamps on your files suggest that it was renamed today, and `ssh` doesn't know to look for a file named `keyforHpc`.

Comment: Maybe you're getting `No such file or directory` because the application that is trying to access the keys doesn't have access to them? The key permissions are quite restrictive (`-rw-r--r--`), what user is trying to access them?

Comment: Have you checked the  space remaining on the home drive. I once had that issue with a full drive.

Answer (score 1):

```
debug1: Trying private key: /home/siddharthan/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/siddharthan/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/siddharthan/.ssh/id_ecdsa
```

vs

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 siddharthan siddharthan 751 Apr 27 17:40 keyforHpc
```

These file names do not match. It's looking for `id_rsa`, `id_dsa`, or `id_ecdsa`, and you have `keyforHpc`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestins. The problem is with the other end. Recently my university cluster was on some maintenance due to which my key got deleted in the cluster. Right now it works fine after being restoring those .ssh files. Regarding the search for id_rsa and id_dsa,as far as i know its just a generic name for private and public key. So either way it will find the appropriate key at the right folder(.ssh). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Do a "man sshd" and read the section AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT.